# Callout: How to add to listplot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have the following code:

```
a = 0; 
n = 50; 
h = N[1/50]; 
uexact[t_] = 
  N[1 + Sqrt[2]*
     Tanh[Sqrt[2]*t + (1/2)*Log[(Sqrt[2] - 1)/(Sqrt[2] + 1)]]]; 
ListPlot[Callout[{Table[{t, uexact[t]}, {t, a, n*h, 0.1}]}, "Exact", 
  Above, 0.4, "CalloutStyle" -> Red, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"\[FivePointedStar]\",\n\
FontSize->18]\)"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
```

I want to use of `Callout` for this code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 0;
n = 50;
h = 1/50;
uexact[t_] = 
  1 + Sqrt[2]*Tanh[Sqrt[2]*t + (1/2)*Log[(Sqrt[2] - 1)/(Sqrt[2] + 1)]] // 
   Simplify;
```

Eliminate the extraneous list brackets around `Table`.

```
ListPlot[Callout[Table[{t, uexact[t]}, {t, a, n*h, 1/10}], "Exact", Above, 
  0.4, "CalloutStyle" -> Red, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"], 
 PlotMarkers -> Style["★", 18], PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]